# Reading a specific area from Excel to a 2D array

Tags: c#, excel, import, oledb

I have a table in Excel and I would like to import a selected area to a 2D array in excel. It must be same 2D array in C#. I have a picture, please look at it. I want to import that area to `int array[81,81]`:

[image: Selected area]

Comment: You can also use EP-Plus library for this. It is available on Nuget and free open source.

Here is a link for it: http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GemBox.Spreadsheet](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/overview) library for this (you can use its Free version to achieve this).

Here is a sample that you can use:

```
ExcelFile workbook = ExcelFile.Load("guncellenmis.xlsx");
ExcelWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.ActiveWorksheet;

int count = 81;
int[,] data = new int[count, count];

// Get range from "C2" to "CE82".
CellRange range = worksheet.Cells.GetSubrangeRelative(1, 2, count, count);
// Or you can retrieve the required range differently, like:
//CellRange range = worksheet.Cells.GetSubrangeRelative("C2:CE82");
//CellRange range = worksheet.Cells.GetSubrangeRelative("C2", "CE82");
// etc.

for (int row = 0; row < range.Height; ++row)
    for (int column = 0; column < range.Width; ++column)
        data[row, column] = range[row, column].IntValue;
```

EDIT:
Is there a reason why you want to export the excel file as 2D array instead of DataTable.
You could retreive the required data as DataTable like the following:

```
ExcelFile workbook = ExcelFile.Load("guncellenmis.xlsx");
ExcelWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.ActiveWorksheet;

DataTable table = worksheet.CreateDataTable(
    new CreateDataTableOptions("C2", 81, 81));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have appericte you.